# Trace Inequality question

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

There is a result in a paper I am reading :

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a constant $C(\epsilon)$ such that 
$$\lVert n \times u\rVert_{H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq \epsilon\lVert \nabla \times u\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} + C(\epsilon)\lVert u\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} $$ where $n$ is the normal.

---

The proof provided : For any $\phi \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega) $, consider the problem 
$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times w) + \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}w = 0 \text{ in } \Omega $$
$$ -n \times (n \times w) = \phi \text{ on } \partial \Omega$$

---

Could someone provide more information?

Comment: You may want to provide the name of the paper.